# Are there any downsides or risks to limiting background processes?

Tags: settings, performance, processes

I enabled developer options on my Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos and then changed "Limit background process" option from *Standard limit* to *No background process*.

After that my phone is working fine, with no hanging problems or no slowness as before.

But my doubt is, will this change affect any process, updates, applications or anything which might cause an error or failure?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Setting this option forces Android to stop each process as soon as it is *empty* (that is, when no *services* are started and no *activities* are on screen for that app).

To be clear: this option won't stop apps that would normally *run* in the background from doing so. Your mail client will still run periodically to check mail, if it's configured to do that. Apps that use Google Cloud Messaging to receive push messages from Internet servers (such as Gmail and Facebook) will still be able to do so. The option would be better named "**Cached** background process limit", since it limits apps that would otherwise show up with that label in the apps manager.

This should lead to your phone working faster.
It might use slightly more or less battery, since it'll use some power to unloading apps from memory earlier than Android usually does it.

The battery impact will depend on your personal usage; If your device doesn't have much ram and/or you don't only use the same few apps all the time, you should get a small battery boost. If you only use the same few apps all the time, you might experience a larger battery drain (from unloading and reloading the apps from memory every time).

Because this is a development option, it can also trigger rare bugs in certain apps, and those apps' developers may not be keen to fix them. One example is that, on Nexus devices running 4.2.2, when this option is on, the in-built Calendar app will keep restarting itself with this option set, because stopping the cached background process causes the calendar's *content provider* to be removed, which causes a loop of services restarting each other to check for calendar updates. If this happens, the loop will run down your battery very quickly.

**Automation**

The setting will be reset every time your device is shut down. If you want to automate setting your preference at boot, you can use tasker with this task: https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8mXwt%2Bxy%2Bkh8K4BRW8pJsHtAYqKGwf%2F0NNidJ2TYe0iDRQsJInNDFFMCPaPm1pYHKuaTMU%3D&id=Task%3AToggle+Background+Process+Limit

You will need to give tasker »Set proces limit permission« using adb with
`adb shell pm grant net.dinglisch.android.taskerm android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT`.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/cn5ufe/task_toggle_androids_background_process_limit/

Comment: The restart bug is still present on Android 6.0....

Comment: @HenryHu "It doesn't work if I change the behaviour of the OS in a way that's only for testing" isn't really much of a bug.

Comment: but the problem may surface in other situations. In a scenario when there is memory pressure, the Calendar app is also being killed and restarts itself. It should really be a service.

Comment: Works like a charm! Enabled it on my XZ2C that had started to chug (still waiting for a new real small phone to update to...).

Comment: This setting has helped my preserve battery life, since my phone isn't overheating because of too many background processes running. The amount of apps silently crashing in the background has also diminished greatly. I have enabled showing errors for unresponsive background apps, to be able force close them before they start slow down and overheat my phone.

Answer (score 10):

I recently found that same setting (i.e., number of processes allowed to run in background), and I reduced that setting on my GT-S7562L from "Standard Limit" to only 1. I immediately saw a significant improvement in performance, and so far there have been no problems.  I made the change out of desperation - my phone had nearly morphed into a brick. It was continually running slow, and would often just simply lock up. I have read that a shortfall of Android systems is that they allow applications to keep grabbing memory until it's gone. Maybe I have solved that problem for my phone. I guess I'll know in a few days, but so far I'm quite happy.

Answer (score 4):

I keep my phone at 4 background processes max, and it has much higher performance than on standard. I receive all my notifications (which I have personally managed in the notifications setting) without any notable difference. I am very pleased that this setting exists in developer options. Also provides for enhanced security and lower battery consumption.

Comment: How does it provide the enhanced security?

Answer (score 2):

Setting limit to phone background process can really improve the performance of your phone. Only, if you open an application, the phone will take a few seconds to load since it will load first the necessary files to be used by a certain apps.

Another advantage, you can prolong the battery life since there is no background process running.

Comment: Is there any reference to backup this answer, or this is based on your experience?

Comment: Maybe the lack of background process compensates the excessive app load?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you may face yourself with is that certain services that run in the background (Tasker, Google Location Services, etc) may quit  unexpectedly. Other than that, I think that there are no other problem with limiting background apps.

Edit: what you selected makes it impossible for apps like I mentioned above to stop working. It won't be possible for gmail, for example, to update you on your received emails.

Comment: No such problems.

Comment: This is misinformation, this setting does NOT affect system services like gmail.  Take a look at your recent applications feature, these are what the setting is referring to as a "background process".  See the top answer by @dan-hulme for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you will choose `no background processes` your phone will revert ro 1995 Nokia mobile. It will stop all types of notification update and prosser data transmission, your phone will only perform for taking a call or messages from your mobile number service provider.

Keep your phone in standard background process until it's not become 2 year old and performing very slow.

You should keep at least 1 or 2 background processes to be in touch with smart and latest information.

There is one other option available which is to just selectively stop all background activities, it's will save your battery life and also reduce (prevent ?) heating problems.

Comment: It's definitely not true that it'll stop any notifications or any background services from running. **Basically all information in this answer is wrong.**