# Background Control in developer options of android 11

Tags: applications, adb, wi-fi, samsung, background-process

[image]

There is a background control option in developer options of android 11. I added an secreen shot. Do options must be enabled or disabled for blocking an app. I did not understand. AASAservice is allowed for background now?    Arka Plan Controlü = Background Control

Comment: Whatever that service , looking at the screenshot, no, it isn't allowed// you would need to provide a translation of AASAservice

Comment: Developer Options / Background Control ( it is down of the background process limit option ) and there are many apps there. Enabling or disabling the options make apps background die. Or what is this option for ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://android.stackexchange.com/q/62387/131553

Comment: I am not asking background process limit, i am asking background control???

Comment: @Halilb1978 "Background check" setting in Developer Options controls `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND` AppOp permission as you do in PMX.

Comment: Thanks, which one blockes background. Enabling or disabling the button ???

Comment: @Halilb1978 enabling allows `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND`, disabling disallows `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND`. The natural way.